# Running total with Over

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a running total of the number of files per opened by day so I can use the data for a graph showing cumulative results.

The data is basically the file opening date, a calculated field showing 'This month' or 'Last Month' depending on the date and the running total field that I'm trying to figure out.

```
Date       Month      Count
====       =====      =====
2019-08-01 Last Month  6
2019-08-02 Last Month  2 
2019-08-03 Last Month  5
```

I want to have a running total...so 6, 8, 13 etc

But all I'm getting is a row count (1,2,3 etc) for my count field.

```
select 
FileDate,

Month,
sum(Count) OVER(PARTITION BY month order by Filedate) as 'Count'

from (
select 
1 as 'Count',
Case
    When month(cast(concat(right(d.var_val,4),substring(d.var_val,4,2),left(d.var_val,2)) as DATE) ) = Month(getdate()) then 'This Month'
    else 'Last Month' 
    end as 'Month'


FROM   data d
left join otherdata m on d.VAR_FileID = m.MAT_FileID
left join otherdata u on m.MAT_Fee_Earner = u.User_ID
left join otherdata br on m.MAT_BranchID = br.BR_ID
WHERE  d.var_no IN ( '1628'  )

and Len(var_val) = 10


)files

where Month(FileDate) in  (MONTH(FileDate()),MONTH(getDate())-1)  
and Year(Filedate) = Year(Getdate())
and Dept = 'Peterborough Property'


group by Month, FileDate, count
GO
```

I'm assuming I've not quite grasped the proper usage of 'OVER' - any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Partition clause indicates when to reset the count, so by partitioning by month you are only counting records for each discreet month to get a running total, over the whole dataset, you don't want the partition clause at all, just the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your clear with `OVER` clause now (with "Sentinel" answer), in which case you should replace desired column as follows, so that `count` continuously increase for all the rows from sub-query based on `order by` clause: [for more details on OVER Clause..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
sum(Count) OVER (Oder by Filedate) as [Count]
-- or 
sum(Count) OVER (Oder by Filedate desc) as [Count]
```